# How to increase scrolling speed on uiwebview

Tags: iphone, ios

i used bellow code for scrolling speed on UIWebview, 
compare to previous scrolling its fine and good, but my clint was not satisfied and he asked like this

> Scrolling still feels stiff.

```
webviews.scrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal;

[webviews loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"site URL"]]];
    webviews.scalesPageToFit =YES;`
```

is there any option to increase scrolling speed?

Answer (score 0):

Have these properties on your UIScrollViewDelegate

```
CGPoint lastOffset;
NSTimeInterval lastOffsetCapture;
BOOL isScrollingFast;
```

Then have this code for your scrollViewDidScroll:

```
- (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {    
    CGPoint currentOffset = self.currentChannelTableView.contentOffset;
    NSTimeInterval currentTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];

    NSTimeInterval timeDiff = currentTime - lastOffsetCapture;
    if(timeDiff > 0.1) {
        CGFloat distance = currentOffset.y - lastOffset.y;
        //The multiply by 10, / 1000 isn't really necessary.......
        CGFloat scrollSpeedNotAbs = (distance * 10) / 1000; //in pixels per millisecond

        CGFloat scrollSpeed = fabsf(scrollSpeedNotAbs);
        if (scrollSpeed > 0.5) {
            isScrollingFast = YES;
            NSLog(@"Fast");
        } else {
            isScrollingFast = NO;
            NSLog(@"Slow");
        }        

        lastOffset = currentOffset;
        lastOffsetCapture = currentTime;
    }
}
```